# jQuery find the first .class, then stop

Tags: jquery

Well, Basicially, I'm looking for a solution.

I have a Table with 2 inputs, 1 disabled input to display the result and other selects within a row. I also have multiple tables.

```
from       | to         | sum       | select
-----------+------------+-----------+-----------
.timeinput | .timeinput | .timesum  | .abwsel
.timeinput | .timeinput | .timesum  | .abwsel
.timeinput | .timeinput | .timesum  | .abwsel
```

I'm calculating the sum from both inputs (which works) and would like to color the `.timesum` orange if the number is between 10.01-11.99 and red if the number is >= 12.

The coloring itself works. However I have the issue, that either only the first `.timesum` of every table or all `.timesums` are colored.

As for the jQuery I have (I just have >= 12 here, to simplify and shorten the code. the issue presits the current line `$(this).next('.timeinputsum').addClass('HrsWarning12');`:

```
$('table').each(function(){
     var sum = 0;

     $(this).find('.timediff').each(function(){
         sum += Number(formatNumber($(this).val(), '.'));

          if(sum >= 10 && sum < 12){

          }
          if(sum >= 12){
               $(this).closest('tr').find('.timediff').addClass('HrsWarning12');
               // $(this).next('.timeinputsum').addClass('HrsWarning12');
          } 
          if(sum < 10) { 

          }
    });

     $(this).find('.timesum').val(formatNumber(sum, ','));
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="0815FirstNameLastNameTable">
     <tr>
          <td><input class="timeinput" id="0815FirstNameLastNameFrom"></td>
          <td><input class="timeinput" id="0815FirstNameLastNameTo"></td>
          <td><input class="timesum" id="0815FirstNameLastNameSum"></td>
          <td><select>...</select></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The problem appears to be with how you traverse the DOM. As such we need to see the actual HTML in order to help you. We also need to know what element `$(this)` refers to in `$(this).find('.timediff')`, so a more complete example of your JS would help too

Comment: Hi Rory, I added the HTML and some more of the jQuery